# Any good sample for an updatable WCF Data Service implementation

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services

I am looking for a good sample implementing an updatable WCF Data Service. I found [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373841.aspx) that shows a sample implementation using IUpdatable, but not sure if I understand this post. There are methods used in this post such as GetTable() and SubmitChanges(), whose implementation is not provided.

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this one most useful - http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/08/31/how-to-perform-crud-operations-in-ado-net-data-services-with-custom-provider.aspx

Thanks all for your replies.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at Alex's blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx) ?
It also has links for creating Data Service for different providers.

Comment: Thanks @Srini, but this one is talking about implementing custom providers. I'd like to use the Reflection provider first, if I can make that work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on IUpdatable implementation:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/IUpdateableLinqToSql

Hope this helps,
Monica

Comment: Thanks @Monica, but this is the same implementation that I found on the MSDN link I have shared in my question.

Comment: Sorry, try this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2008/04/10/iupdatable-ado-net-data-services-framework.aspx