# Posting data to a WCF OData Service from JQuery

Tags: jquery, wcf-data-services, odata, put

I've been breaking my head over this one, and I just can't spot the issue.
I don't have that much experience with WCF services, so I hope it might be something simple I've missed.

I've set up this WCF OData Service exposing our entity model like so:

```
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }
```

Now I've been accessing that data using jQuery without a problem, but once I update the jsonp-object I fetched, and PUT it back to the service to update the database, I'm getting back a HTTP 501 code (Not Implemented).

Here's the code I've written to PUT the object back to the service:

```
    function commitData() {
         $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:7634/API/Service.svc/tbl_bericht_vertalingen/?$format=json&Authorization=' + userGuid,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'PUT',
            data: jsonObject,
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function () { alert("oops!"); },
            success: updateCallback
        }); 
    }

    function updateCallback(result) {
        var record = result["d"];
        alert("Updated on record with ID " + record.Id);
    }
```

the jsonObject is the same object I received from the service earlier, with some updated properties.

As stated, calling this bit of jQuery results in me getting back a '501 - Not Implemented' from the service.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whenever you get back an error code from a WCF Data Service, consider using the steps in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx) blog post to get more context on what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your service is not configured to be updatable. In order to make your service support updates, you must provide an implementation of IUpdatable (or IDataServiceUpdateProvider).

If you're using the Entity Framework as your provider, this should just work out of the box. But if you're using a reflection provider, you'll need to implement this interface yourself. Perhaps the simplest way of providing this interface is to implement it on the "T" class in your DataService.

For more information, check out this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg191846.aspx (try searching for IUpdatable and IDataServiceUpdateProvider), or this other stack overflow question: [Any good sample for an updatable WCF Data Service implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827365/any-good-sample-for-an-updatable-wcf-data-service-implementation)